# "Operation must use an updateable query" in MS Access when the Updated Table is the same as the source

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2016

The challenge is to update a table by scanning that same table for information. In this case, I want to find how many entries I received in an Upload dataset that have the same key (effectively duplicate instructions).

I tried the obvious code:

```
UPDATE Base AS TAR 
INNER JOIN (select cdKey, count(*) as ct FROM Base GROUP BY cdKey) AS CHK
        ON TAR.cdKey = CHK.cdKey
SET ctReferences = CHK.ct
```

This resulted in a non-updateable complaint. Some workarounds talked about adding `DISTINCTROW`, but that made no difference.

I tried creating a view (query in Ms/Access parlance); same failure.

Then I projected the set (`SELECT cdKey, count(*) INTO TEMP FROM Base GROUP BY cdKey`), and substituted TEMP for the INNER JOIN which worked.

Conclusion: reflexive updates are also non-updateable.

Comment: This was not the reason. The subquery has a `GROUP BY` clause, which automatically makes the whole query non-updateable. No exceptions. -- Links: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html) and [Allen Browne: Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Answer (score 0):

An initial thought was to embed a sub-select in the update, for example:

```
UPDATE Base TAR SET TAR.ctReferences = (select count(*) from Base CHK where CHK.cd = TAR.cd)
```

This also failed.

As this is part of a job I am calling, this SQL (like the other statements) are all strings executed by `CurrentDb.Execute` statements. I thought maybe I could make this a `DLookup`, I found that as `cd` is a string, I had a gaggle of double- and triple-quoted elements that was too messy to read (and maintain).

Best solution was to write a function so I could avoid having to do any sort of string manipulation. Hence, in a module there's a function:

```
Public Function PassHelperCtOccurs(ByRef cdX As String) As Long

  PassHelperCtOccurs = DLookup("count(*)", "Base", "cd='" & cdX & "'")
  
End Function
```

And the call is:

```
 CurrentDb().Execute ("UPDATE Base SET ctOccursCd =PassHelperCtOccurs(cd)")
```